# Eclipse in Windows/ C++ / HelloWorld - Error starting process. Cannot run program "C:..\Hello World\src\Hello World.cpp": Launching failed

Tags: c++, eclipse, installation

I'm trying to set up my Eclipse for C++ coding in Windows 8 and I came up against some hurdles in creating the 'HelloWorld.cpp'. The error pointed out is:

- **Error starting process. Cannot run program "C:..\Hello World\src\Hello World.cpp": Launching failed**

The software used is:

- eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64, placed in C:\Program Files\
- MinGW, placed in C:\
- msys, placed in C:\

Searching the StackOverflow answers I made the following changes/attempts:

1. I first build and then run
2. run as local c/c++ application
3. g++ --version, gcc --version, make --version : check these in the cmd and they are installed
4. Project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Language: I chose GNU C++
5. Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Tool chain Editor: I set the current toolchain with the value 'MinGW GCC'
6. Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers : I chose PE Windows Parsers
7. I've used both Debug and Release options as active
8. in the System's Properties->Environment Variables->User's Variables->Path : I added the two values C:\MinGW\bin and C:\msys\1.0\bin

So, I don't know what else to do and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Looking forward to any ideas!

Thanks in advance,

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering!

I just found out what the problem was. In **Project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols** in the **"include"** tab I had to **add** the following directories:

In "GNU C":

- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include
- $MINGW_HOME\include
- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include-fixed

In "GNU C++" :

- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include\c++
- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include\c++\mingw32
- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include\c++\backward
- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include
- $MINGW_HOME\include
- $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.x\include-fixed

These are also mentioned in the **link** that you have already mentioned:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

In section 2.1 just after step 2!

I hope this post will help others so as not to waste much time searching.

George

Answer (score 0):

There may have been an error during the setup of Eclipse during the installation process. Alternatively, you may have missed some package(s) of MinGW during the installation process. What I recommend is that you watch a video on YouTube for installing Eclipse for **C++** on **Windows 8**. You can try this video:

> [How to Install and Setup Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Development on Windows](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TXbuATMlVNY) - Youtube

When watching the video, you can see where you have gone wrong in the installation process, and fix that. If you followed the instructions perfectly, then maybe you could follow these instructions on running your first program on Eclipse:

> [Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) for C/C++ Programming | How To Install Eclipse CDT 8.2 and Get Started](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) - Website link

For the website, you can skip to section 2.1 directly.

If you followed the instructions perfectly, than I would recommend uninstalling everyting and then redoing the installation. Alternatively, you could reconsider using Eclipse and go for another IDE like Codeblocks, Visual Studio, etc... __However, this should only be a LAST RESORT when everything else i suggested above does not work.

Good luck!